# Server Files Download

Tags: performance, download

I have a transactional database with very large number of records and concurrent access.i need to provide download facility to the clients.the download file size can be even up to 300MB.so if i provide the download facility directly from server memory there will a performance issue.is there any other alternative way to achieve this?